# How to get WPF default Styles and ControlTemplates for DataGrid and sub controls?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, controltemplate

I need to make several changes to the default Styles and ControlTemplates of all major UserControls of my application. I found this very easy to do for allmost all UserControls (RightClick control in VS2015 designer => Edit template => Edit a copy...) and maybe a little bit more complicated for the more complex ones like the Calendar, but I totally fail for DataGrid and its now sub controls.

While it is of course easy to get the style and template for the DataGrid itself I still need the styles for DataGridRow, DataGridRowHeader, DataGridColumnHeader, DataGridCell, ... I do not even know all possible sub elements.

I searched the internet for about half a day now and could not find any solution to my issue:

- If I check the [MSDN for default styles of the DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) it gives me a bad example that contains weird stuff like FrozenGridDataGrid and other stuff that is not contained in the referenced Namespaces and assemblies. I'm not sure if this example is targeted towards Silverlight only...
- Tools like ['Show Me The Templates!'](http://sellsbrothers.com/2091) do not list the DataGrid...
- The BAML Viewer addin for .Net Reflector does only show me my custom styles but not the default ones. Targeting for example the PresentationFramework.Aero.dll does not work.
- I even found an [example by Jamie Rodriguez on the MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx) on how to style the DataGrid which gets very close to what I need - but then again I do not know how close his code is to the defaults, if something is missing and also his result looks like a color palette...

Can anyone please tell me what styles and templates I need to cover the whole DataGrid and where I can get their defaults?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Blend.

[image]

You will get all templates.

Comment: Your answer is correct, although you would not even need to open Blend: The same menu is available in the Visual Studio designer just underneath the menu item that I have descriped above. I just noticed that the context menus of Blend an the designer in VS are about identical...
The solution was there all the time - I just did not notice it. Thanks for your help - I have to cry now...